# Linker errors when attempting to convert const char * to LPTSTR

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, compilation, linker

I have the following code snippet that converts a const char * to a LPTSTR, however I get linker errors when I compile.

```
char * pCopy3 = NULL;
    if (sizeof(TCHAR) == sizeof(char))
    {
        size_t size = strlen(words[2].c_str());
        pCopy3 = new char[size + 1];
        strcpy(pCopy3, words[2].c_str());
    }
```

The linker errors are as follows

```
Error   19  error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   STablUpd.exe    1   1   STablUpd
Error   17  error LNK2005: "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > * args" (?args@@3PAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A) already defined in maindlg.obj  tabledlg.obj    STablUpd
Error   18  error LNK2005: "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > * words" (?words@@3PAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A) already defined in maindlg.obj    tabledlg.obj    STablUpd
Error   16  error LNK2005: "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > cmdArgs" (?cmdArgs@@3V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A) already defined in maindlg.obj    tabledlg.obj    STablUpd
Error   13  error LNK2005: "int __cdecl Main_OnInitDialog(struct HWND__ *,struct HWND__ *,long)" (?Main_OnInitDialog@@YAHPAUHWND__@@0J@Z) already defined in maindlg.obj    tabledlg.obj    STablUpd
Error   8   error LNK2005: "int __stdcall Main_DlgProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?Main_DlgProc@@YGHPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z) already defined in maindlg.obj tabledlg.obj    STablUpd
Error   15  error LNK2005: "struct HINSTANCE__ * g_hInstApp" (?g_hInstApp@@3PAUHINSTANCE__@@A) already defined in maindlg.obj   tabledlg.obj    STablUpd
Error   9   error LNK2005: "void __cdecl Main_OnBrowse(struct HWND__ *)" (?Main_OnBrowse@@YAXPAUHWND__@@@Z) already defined in maindlg.obj  tabledlg.obj    STablUpd
Error   10  error LNK2005: "void __cdecl Main_OnClose(struct HWND__ *,int)" (?Main_OnClose@@YAXPAUHWND__@@H@Z) already defined in maindlg.obj   tabledlg.obj    STablUpd
Error   11  error LNK2005: "void __cdecl Main_OnCommand(struct HWND__ *,int,struct HWND__ *,unsigned int)" (?Main_OnCommand@@YAXPAUHWND__@@H0I@Z) already defined in maindlg.obj    tabledlg.obj    STablUpd
Error   12  error LNK2005: "void __cdecl Main_OnDisplay(struct HWND__ *)" (?Main_OnDisplay@@YAXPAUHWND__@@@Z) already defined in maindlg.obj    tabledlg.obj    STablUpd
Error   14  error LNK2005: _WinMain@16 already defined in maindlg.obj   tabledlg.obj    STablUpd
```

Comment: The error message clearly states the problem. You have **multiple** (not *multiply* as shown in the error message) definitions.

Comment: You error has nothing directly to do with string conversion. You are building your program wrongly. How you are building it wrongly is impossible to say from the information provided. Try describing what files you have in your program, how you compile them, which files include what other files etc.

Comment: @JesseGood:  The message is correctly using the adverb form of multiply.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Dang, I didn't know multiply can be used as an adverb. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @john However, when I don't include the snippet - it compiles fine.

Comment: @user1661022 There is no way in the world that those lines of code cause those errors. Look at the errors, ` _WinMain@16 already defined in maindlg.obj   tabledlg.obj` for instance. Do you see WinMain anywhere in the above snippet of code? But anyway, suit yourself, without further information it is impossible to say what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume the code snippet you have shown converts std::string to char*. In that case the code is correct and there should be no errors when compiling that code (except strcpy warning).

You originally asked for char* to LPTSTR conversion. You could do it like this (for UNICODE character set):

```
char *test;
wchar_t *bla=new wchar_t[size];
swprintf(bla, size, L"%hs", test);
LPTSTR bla2=bla;
```

Alternatively if you use multi-byte character set:

```
char *test;
LPTSTR bla2=test;
```